# Can not navigate back using window.location.href

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, icenium

i am developing an App using Icenium Graphite.

at one point i am showing list of people using Kendo Grid which is having Edit button.
using this edit button user can edit that particular record.
when user clicks on Edit button that record gets open in another form.
user saves the edited record and get back to same page which showing Grid.
for navigation back to Grid Page i am using 
window.location.href = "index.html#tabstrip-login";

but it is not working in this case.

please so let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: You want `window.history.back()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history If you just want the url, `window.location.href` has no brackets

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
var url = "";
if (typeof window.location.href != "undefined") {
       url =window.location
}else{ 
       url = document.location//  or try this document.URL
}
```

Comment: sorry there is no brackets i have corrected in above post it is window.location.href = "index.html#tabstrip-login";

Comment: @ Somnath Kharat ..didn't get you??

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm assuming you are using Kendo UI Mobile in your application. If so, you'll need to use the [Application object's `navigate()` method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/application#methods-navigate) to switch views.

For instance suppose you have an application with the following markup:

```
<div id="one" data-role="view">
    One
</div>
<div id="two" data-role="view">
    Two
</div>
```

You can create your `Application` using this:

```
var application = new kendo.mobile.Application( document.body, { initial: "#one" } );
```

Then switch views by calling `navigate()`. This switches the app to its second view:

```
application.navigate( "#two" );
```